# How do you type ignore all instances of a particular type?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Originally from [this gitter question](https://gitter.im/python/typing?at=61f9d03ed4102444803fce0f).

Let's say I'm dealing with some class `FancyClass`, which mypy doesn't understand well (e.g. let's say it fails to properly infer its attributes). That class could be 3rd party, so I can't easily fix that (though I guess I could write type stubs?)... So: I want to ignore any errors on any instance of that class and/or some specific instances of a class. Of course, I can add `# type: ignore` on each line that the class instances are giving me errors, but in practice that could become intractable (e.g. when I interact with the class instance on many lines).

```py
a = FancyClass()

a.foo = "hi" # gives error, because mypy fails to infer what attributes this instance will have
```

What are my options to add an ignore that applies to any instances of such class or at least to specific instance of such class?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to ignore a single instance of any object, is to tell type checkers that it is Any. For instance:

```
from typing import Any, cast

a = cast(Any, FancyClass())
```

The same trick can be used on the class itself, to achieve the same effect as ktb's answer:

```
FancyClassButShutsMypyUp = cast(Any, FancyClass)
a = FancyClassButShutsMypyUp()
```

A related trick, if you have control over the definition of `FancyClass`, is the following:

```
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    # can't actually subclass Any at runtime
    AnyBaseClass = Any
else:
    AnyBaseClass = object

class Mystery(AnyBaseClass): ...
```

This isn't equivalent to the above, since if `Mystery` has methods and attributes defined on it, type checkers will be able to resolve them, but that's often a useful difference. Potential use cases include monkey patching, duck typing through strictly typed interfaces, dynamic metaclasses, etc.

As the question alludes to, writing stubs (or using a stub generator) can be a good solution. You can combine the two approaches, having exact types in your stub where useful, and using `Any` trickery where needed.

Finally, mypy has various options for ignoring all types from a given package (the "import following" options), see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#following-imports

Edit: In Python 3.11, you can inherit from Any at runtime without the `if TYPE_CHECKING` dance above. On older Pythons, you can inherit from `typing_extensions.Any`.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not aware of any way to ignore all instances of a particular type across a whole package, one common idiom is to conditionally import the class or `Any` if you are in a `TYPE_CHECKING` context.

For example:

```py
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    FancyClass = typing.Any
else:
    from module import FancyClass

a = FancyClass()
reveal_type(a)  # note: Reveal type is "Any"

a.foo = "hi"
```